# stuck with my vba code to filter find data based on date

Tags: vba, excel

This works fine when I am using date, but If i am trying to used input box for entering my desired date to get data it doesn't work... Any Suggestions??

```
sub datewise()
Dim lastrow As Long, erow As Long, i As Integer, lastcolumn As Long
Dim today, tomorrow As String
Dim k As Integer, j As Integer, s As Integer


today = InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter the date in d/m/yyyy format", Title:="Shift Date", Default:="7/6/2018")

'today = Date
'tomorrow = today + 1

lastrow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
 j = 3
 Do While j < 40
 If today = Sheet1.Cells(2, j) Then
 Sheet1.Cells(2, j).Copy
 Sheet1.Paste Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(2, 2)
 Sheet1.Paste Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(2, 4)
 Sheet1.Paste Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(2, 6)
 k = j
 Exit Do
 End If
 j = j + 1
 Loop

 '------1800 Shift------


i = 3
erow = 4
Do While i <= lastrow

If Sheet1.Cells(i, k).Value = 18 Then
Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Copy
Sheet1.Paste Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(erow, 1)

Sheet1.Cells(i, 2).Copy
Sheet1.Paste Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(erow, 2)

erow = erow + 1
End If
i = i + 1
Loop



Application.CutCopyMode = False
Sheet2.Columns().AutoFit
Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

I need to use my mastersheet date and filter it based on the date I need, I was thinking maybe I need to use auto filter option but the date data is in a row so filter also can't be used. This code works fine if I use date variable

Answer (score 1):

I would force the specific format:

```
Sub INeedADate()
    Dim today As Date, d As String, arry
    d = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter the date in d/m/yyyy format", Title:="Shift Date", Default:="7/6/2018", Type:=2)
    arry = Split(d, "/")
    today = DateSerial(arry(2), arry(1), arry(0))
End Sub
```

The **2,1,0** order matches your input format.

Comment: @KasiViswanath Thank you for the feedback,

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try `DateValue()` function

```
today = DateValue(InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter the date in d/m/yyyy format", Title:="Shift Date", Default:="7/6/2018"))
```

Comment: I believe DateValue expects MDY, not DMY but CDate should pick up on the user's regional short date settings.

Answer (score 0):

VBA is very EN-US-centric and you are trying to get it to accept a DMY date when it expects a MDY date.

True dates are nothing more than numbers; literally 1 for every day past 31-Dec-1899. It doesn't matter whether you use a MDY date like 6/10/2018 or 43261 when comparing to a cell's value; either will match or not match as the case may be.

If you are going to request a DMY date, then you are going to have to convert it to MDY or a number before using it in VBA.

```
Dim today as long, tomorrow As String, tmp as string

tmp = InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter the date in d/m/yyyy format", Title:="Shift Date", Default:=format(date, "d/m/yyyy"))

today =dateserial(split(tmp, "/")(2), split(tmp, "/")(1), split(tmp, "/")(0))

Do While j < 40
    If today = Sheet1.Cells(2, j).value2 Then
        ...
    End If
    j = j + 1
Loop
```

I changed your default InputBox value but if you are going to make it static, do not use an ambiguous DMY/MDY value like 7/6/2018.